# Android Studio 2 emulator no logcat messages

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-logcat

I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 and if I start apps on any real device it's ok and I see all stuff in Logcat. But if I start any emulated device (the new Android Studio emulator), my Logcat is empty. Even if I set "No Filters", I see no usual system messages, just empty field.

any one give a solution ,Thanks in advance

EDIT: Restarting Android Studio with disconnected real device helped. Problem solved

Comment: What happens if you restart logcat and run the app again?

Comment: nothing. And it has nothing to do with the app, even system messages are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the device selected in logcat is the correct one (in your case, the emulator).

Also, to restart adb, you can run `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` (adb location depends on the operating system)